# Inheritance-Need Guidance

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, unity-game-engine, constructor

I am a novice programmer, so sorry if this is a really stupid question. I need to pass a value from one class to another. If I am not mistaken, this would be done through inheritance, but there seems to be something I am missing. Any help would be welcome. I am writing in C# within Unity.

```
    public class baseStats{
    private int STAMINA;

    public static int Stamina{
       get{return STAMINA;}
       set{STAMINA = value;}   
   }
}
```

The above is a sample of my parent class. Here is my child class:

```
  public class Profile : baseStats {

   private static int PROFILE_STAMINA;

    private void Stats ()
  {
    PROFILE_STAMINA = Stamina;

  }

   public static int profileStamina
  {
    get{return PROFILE_STAMINA;}
  }

}
```

In a third script I created for the purposes of debugging, I wrote:

```
 public class debug:MonoBehaviour{
      void Start(){
           Debug.Log(Profile.profileStamina.ToString());
   }
}
```

It says I need an object reference for the non-static field, method, or property
'Profile.Profile.Stamina'. Easy fix: make everything static (I believe I need to make constructors or something like that to avoid having to use static all the time. A little help with that would be great!). Once error-free, I ran the program and the console outputs 0 for my profile stamina. I am really confused as to what is going on. Sorry this is such a long post, and thanks for any help I get.

Comment: How is `profileStamina` in your third script defined? Please update your code with that. Just provide your complete third script like you did for others.

Comment: That is the full script. http://imgur.com/tasBn6r

Comment: You had `Profile.profileStamina` in the picture. Why not update your question with that. It's good to just copy your code directly fro your IDE to SO to prevent unnecessary questions from people. Also, your `Profile` script is not included in the Question. I don't know how people can help without this. Please make sure the other code here is the-same as the code in your IDE.

Comment: Okay I will keep that in mind. Sorry for overlooking that.

Comment: Your Profile script is still missing...

Comment: Yeah I was on break at school while writing this. I copied and pasted the text I have from my all my scripts and updated this post. Hopefully this provides what you are looking for. If not then I guess I am not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. `Profile` is updated. I managed to answer your question without that information and but it seems like I guessed it right. If you want people to answer your question quickly just make sure the code in your question is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to pass a value from one class to another. If I am not
>   mistaken, this would be done through inheritance.

No, you don't need inheritance to pass values from one class to another. If you don't know what inheritance is, you shouldn't be using it. It's very likely you don't need it. The-same thing applies to the `static` keyword. New programmers tend to make everything `static` when they don't know what the `new` keyword is used for.

Simply create a new instance of the `Stats` script inside the `Profile` constructor script. To use the `Profile` script, create a new instance of it which will automatically call the constructor that will create a new instance of the `Stats` script. You shouldn't be doing this with static variables and functions. Totally unnecessary. Values can be passed to another script with auto property or function but my solution used auto property to make it simple.

```
public class Stats
{
    private int STAMINA;

    public int Stamina
    {
        get { return STAMINA; }
        set { STAMINA = value; }
    }
}

public class Profile
{
    private Stats stats;
    private int PROFILE_STAMINA;

    //Init only
    public Profile()
    {
        stats = new Stats();
    }

    //Init with Stats stamina and profileStamina stamina values
    public Profile(int stamina, int profileStamina)
    {
        stats = new Stats();
        stats.Stamina = stamina;
        PROFILE_STAMINA = profileStamina;
    }

    //Stamina From Profile
    public int profileStamina
    {
        get { return PROFILE_STAMINA; }
        set { PROFILE_STAMINA = value; }
    }

    //Stamina From Stats
    public int Stamina
    {
        get { return stats.Stamina; }
        set { stats.Stamina = value; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class debug:MonoBehaviour{
Profile profile = null;

void Start()
{

    //Creata new profile and set Stats stamina and ProfileStamina stamina values
    profile = new Profile(10, 5);
    profile.Stamina = 60;
    profile.profileStamina = 60;
    Debug.Log(profile.profileStamina.ToString());
}
```

Also take time and learn about [Classes](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson07),[Properties](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson10).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write an insightful response. This is very helpful.

Comment: @TimothyWhite You are welcome. don't forget to visit those links I posted. You need to learn about creating instance of class. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a non-static from a static property.

This code is the main problem:

```
public static int Stamina{
   get{return STAMINA;}
   set{STAMINA = value;}   
}
```

`STAMINA` is defined as `private int STAMINA`. It isn't static. Quite simply, this means that inside every object of the type `baseStats` you have an int called `STAMINA` you can fill in. However, you're *not working on an object there*; you're in a static function, which is something that can be executed *without* an object. Since there is no object, there is no `STAMINA` int either; there's no object to get or fill in that property *on*.

On that note, your function `profileStats()` has the same issue; it tries to access the non-static `STAMINA` as well, again without having any kind of object. Any reference to just plain `STAMINA` is actually to `this.STAMINA`, and inside a static, there's no `this`.

I'm not sure what the purpose of this whole setup is; personally I'd avoid using statics containing global data like that. Instead I'd just keep an object around containing the necessary properties which is simply passed on to any functions that need to access the data in it. But anyway, from what I can see, you simply forgot to put `static` on that `private int STAMINA`.

Side note: this is completely unrelated to inheritance. Since `Stamina` is a public static property, and statics can't be inherited (except in some peculiar advanced cases with inherited generics), your "child class" never even needs the parent class as parent, as long as it references `baseStats.Stamina` instead of `STAMINA`. This can easily be shown by making both *classes* static.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I will revise my code according to your instructions.